# Unsuccessful when trying to save an EKEvent

Tags: ios, objective-c, ekevent

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IM9XKFTXuKk), but I'm getting an error at the beginning of `if (err = noErr) {`

This is my code:

```
#import "CalendarViewController.h"
#import <EventKit/EventKit.h>

@interface CalendarViewController ()

@end

@implementation CalendarViewController

-(IBAction) createEvent {

EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc ] init];

EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];

NSDate *startDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSDate *endDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];

event.title = @"Title for new event";
event.startDate = startDate;
event.endDate = endDate;
event.allDay = YES;

[event setCalendar: [eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];

NSError *err;


[eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];
if (err == noErr) {

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle:@"Event Created"
                          message:@"How about that?"
                          delegate:nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil];

        [alert show];
        [alert release];
}

[startDate release];
[endDate release];
[eventStore release];
}
```

I'm a beginner to this and it's part of my HSC but I'm not getting it to work properly. I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The currently accepted answer is a little misleading.

When you have methods in Cocoa that return a `BOOL` and contain an indirect reference to an NSError object, you must check the return value before checking the error object - because only when the return value is `NO` is the error object guaranteed to be valid.

```
NSError *err;

BOOL success = [eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];
if (success) {

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle:@"Event Created"
                          message:@"How about that?"
                          delegate:nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil];

        [alert show];
        [alert release];
} else {
    if (!err) {
        // If the event is not modified then the return is `NO` and there is no error
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle:@"Event Unchanged"
                          message:@"The event wasn't modified, so there is nothing to save."
                          delegate:nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil];

        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    } else {
        // The method was unsuccessful and there is a valid error
        NSString *errorMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" Unable to save because: %@", [err localizedDescription];
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle:@"Error!"
                          message:errorMessage"
                          delegate:nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil];

        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
}
```

A little wordier than the way I would actually do it, but you should get the idea